# C# OpenFileDialog only shows XP-Style in Win7

Tags: winforms, windows-7, openfiledialog

I'm working with a .NET 3.5 application that is using System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog. However, no matter what I do, the open dialog only shows the XP-Style version. I've made the code as simple as possible:

```
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog()
//openFileDialog.AutoUpgradeEnabled = true; //Adding this line does nothing

if(DialogResult.OK == openFileDialog.ShowDialog())
{ ... }
```

No matter what I do, the dialog always shows the old XP-Style version instead of the new Vista+ version. I also noticed that when I debug and look at some parameters, there's a protected member variable somewhere in the chain: `SettingsSupportVistaDialog`, which in this instance is set to `false`. I'm not sure if that is the issue, or where/why this could be getting set.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Here's a screenshot of the existing (XP-style) dialog
[image: XP-Style Dialog]

Here's what I want it to look like:
[image]

Comment: Try `openFileDialog.ShowHelp=false` and see if makes any difference. Also are you sure you get XP style?! put an screenshot!

Comment: setting openFileDialog.ShowHelp=false had no effect. I added screenshots of what the current dialog looks like and what I want it to look like.

Comment: Well sure you are getting XP style. What version of Visual Studio are you using? Can you try with framework v4.0 or higher to confirm you also get XP style with that? I also assume you are on VISA or Win7!! sory for dumb question :P

Comment: I'm using VS2008, and the project I'm working on is very large and has a complex build procedure, so I'm not very confident about being able to swap in the v4.0 framework. However, I can try a simple application and see if the same problem occurs using 3.5 and 4.0. (Also, I am on a Win7 machine)

Comment: Are you using the System.Windows.Forms namespace or the Microsoft.Win32 namespace to get the dialog?

Comment: System.Windows.Forms. I even tried explicitly doing `System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();`, and it still gave me the XP style.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem. I had to dig into the .NET 3.5 source code, but it turns out that if `Application.VisualStyleState` isn't set to `ClientAreaEnabled` or `ClientAndNonClientAreasEnabled` the old XP-style dialog will be used.

Comment: I love to read "I had to dig into the .NET 3.5 source code". This wasn't possible some weeks ago...